# How to tell if a surrogate pair Unicode character is supported by the font?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi, uniscribe

I was able to find the [following method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34278430/843732) of determining if a `Unicode-16` character is supported by a font. Unfortunately that doesn't work for [surrogate pair Unicode characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/intl/surrogates-and-supplementary-characters), since `WCRANGE` struct supported by [`GetFontUnicodeRanges`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getfontunicoderanges) function returns only `WCHAR` (16-bit) parameters as output.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HFONT hFont = NULL;

    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            LOGFONT lf = {0};
            lf.lfHeight = -64;
            ::StringCchCopy(lf.lfFaceName, _countof(lf.lfFaceName), L"Arial");

            hFont = ::CreateFontIndirect(&lf);
        }
        break;

        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

            RECT rcClient = {0};
            ::GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcClient);

            HGDIOBJ hOldFont = ::SelectObject(hdc, hFont);

            LPCTSTR pStr = L">\U0001F609<";
            int nLn = wcslen(pStr);

            RECT rc = {20, 20, rcClient.right, rcClient.bottom};
            ::DrawText(hdc, pStr, nLn, &rc, DT_NOPREFIX | DT_SINGLELINE);

            ::SelectObject(hdc, hOldFont);

            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;

    //....
```

If I run it on Windows 10, I get this:

[image]

But this is what I'm getting on Windows 7:

[image]

So what is the way to tell if that middle character is not going to be rendered?

---

PS. I also attempted to use *badly documented* [Uniscribe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/intl/uniscribe), and a modified version of [this tutorial](https://maxradi.us/documents/uniscribe/) as an example. But no matter what I did, it failed to produce a discernible outcome between Win10 and Win7. If it helps to answer this question, here's the code I experimented with:

```
//Call from WM_PAINT handler
std::wstring str;
test02(hdc, pStr, str);

RECT rc0 = {0, 200, rcClient.right, rcClient.bottom};
::DrawText(hdc, str.c_str(), str.size(), &rc0, DT_NOPREFIX | DT_SINGLELINE);
```

and then:

```
void test02(HDC hDc, LPCTSTR pStr, std::wstring& str)
{
    //'str' = receives debugging outcome (needs to be printed on the screen)

    //SOURCE:
    //      https://maxradi.us/documents/uniscribe/

    HRESULT hr;
    SCRIPT_STRING_ANALYSIS ssa = {0};

    int nLn = wcslen(pStr);

    hr = ::ScriptStringAnalyse(hDc,
        pStr,
        nLn,
        1024,
        -1,
        SSA_GLYPHS,
        0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &ssa);

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        const SCRIPT_PROPERTIES **g_ppScriptProperties;
        int g_iMaxScript;

        hr = ::ScriptGetProperties(&g_ppScriptProperties, &g_iMaxScript);
        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            const int cMaxItems = 20;
            SCRIPT_ITEM si[cMaxItems + 1];
            SCRIPT_ITEM *pItems = si;
            int cItems;                 //Receives number of glyphs

            SCRIPT_CONTROL scrCtrl = {0};
            SCRIPT_STATE scrState = {0};

            hr = ::ScriptItemize(pStr, nLn, cMaxItems, &scrCtrl, &scrState, pItems, &cItems);
            if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                FormatAdd2(str, L"cItems=%d: ", cItems);

                int nCntGlyphs = nLn * 4;
                WORD* pGlyphs = new WORD[nCntGlyphs];
                WORD* pLogClust = new WORD[nLn];
                SCRIPT_VISATTR* pSVs = new SCRIPT_VISATTR[nCntGlyphs];

                //Go through each run
                for(int i = 0; i < cItems; i++)
                {
                    FormatAdd2(str, L"[%d]:", i);

                    SCRIPT_CACHE sc = NULL;
                    int nCntGlyphsWrtn = 0;
                    int iPos = pItems[i].iCharPos;
                    const WCHAR* pP = &pStr[iPos];
                    int cChars = i + 1 < cItems ? pItems[i + 1].iCharPos - iPos : nLn - iPos;

                    hr = ::ScriptShape(hDc, &sc, pP, cChars,
                        nCntGlyphs, &pItems[i].a, pGlyphs, pLogClust, pSVs, &nCntGlyphsWrtn);

                    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        std::wstring strGlyphs;
                        for(int g = 0; g < nCntGlyphsWrtn; g++)
                        {
                            FormatAdd2(strGlyphs, L"%02X,", pGlyphs[g]);
                        }

                        std::wstring strLogClust;
                        for(int w = 0; w < cChars; w++)
                        {
                            FormatAdd2(strLogClust, L"%02X,", pLogClust[w]);
                        }

                        std::wstring strSVs;
                        for(int g = 0; g < nCntGlyphsWrtn; g++)
                        {
                            FormatAdd2(strSVs, L"%02X,", pSVs[g]);
                        }

                        FormatAdd2(str, L"c=%d {G:%s LC:%s SV:%s} ", nCntGlyphsWrtn, strGlyphs.c_str(), strLogClust.c_str(), strSVs.c_str());


                        int* pAdvances = new int[nCntGlyphsWrtn];
                        GOFFSET* pOffsets = new GOFFSET[nCntGlyphsWrtn];
                        ABC abc = {0};

                        hr = ::ScriptPlace(hDc, &sc, pGlyphs, nCntGlyphsWrtn, pSVs, &pItems[i].a, pAdvances, pOffsets, &abc);
                        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
                        {
                            std::wstring strAdvs;
                            for(int g = 0; g < nCntGlyphsWrtn; g++)
                            {
                                FormatAdd2(strAdvs, L"%02X,", pAdvances[g]);
                            }

                            std::wstring strOffs;
                            for(int g = 0; g < nCntGlyphsWrtn; g++)
                            {
                                FormatAdd2(strOffs, L"u=%02X v=%02X,", pOffsets[g].du, pOffsets[g].dv);
                            }


                            FormatAdd2(str, L"{a=%d,b=%d,c=%d} {A:%s OF:%s}", abc.abcA, abc.abcB, abc.abcC, strAdvs.c_str(), strOffs.c_str());
                        }


                        delete[] pAdvances;
                        delete[] pOffsets;

                    }



                    //Clear cache
                    hr = ::ScriptFreeCache(&sc);
                    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
                }

                delete[] pSVs;
                delete[] pGlyphs;
                delete[] pLogClust;
            }
        }

        hr = ::ScriptStringFree(&ssa);
        assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
    }
}

std::wstring& FormatAdd2(std::wstring& str, LPCTSTR pszFormat, ...)
{
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, pszFormat);
    int nSz = _vsctprintf(pszFormat, argList) + 1;

    TCHAR* pBuff = new TCHAR[nSz];      //One char for last null
    pBuff[0] = 0;
    _vstprintf_s(pBuff, nSz, pszFormat, argList);
    pBuff[nSz - 1] = 0;

    str.append(pBuff);

    delete[] pBuff;

    va_end(argList);

    return str;
}
```

---

**EDIT:** I was able to create a [demo GUI app](https://github.com/ddbb2017/TestTofuGui) that demonstrates the solution suggested by [Barmak Shemirani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4603670/barmak-shemirani) below.

Comment: Have you tried GetGlyphIndicesW ?

Comment: @AlexanderGutenev: Yes. Same thing. It doesn't work with glyphs "wider" than 16 bits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

character is actually not supported in Windows 10 Arial font. Windows 10 uses `"Segoe UI Emoji"` as fallback font for that particular code point.

So first we have to figure out if fallback font is used. Then check the glyph index to see if it is tofu character (usually shown as square sign `▯`)

We can use meta file to find if font substitution is used. Select that font in to `HDC`.

Use `ScriptGetFontProperties` to find the values for unsupported glyphs.

Use `GetCharacterPlacement` to find the glyph indices for the string. If the glyph index matches unsupported glyphs, then the code point is being printed as tofu `▯`.

---

**Edit:**

If you try to print Chinese character etc. then you have to choose the appropriate font (SimSun for Chinese)

This part is done by `IMLangFontLink`. It's a different type of font substitution. 
The example below will test for single code point (it can be expanded to handle a string).

If `Segoe UI` font is selected, then for the Chinese character `请`, it will switch `Segoe UI` to `SimSun`.

For emojis, it will switch `Segoe UI` to `Segoe UI Emoji`

See also this article in [oldnewthing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040716-00/?p=38413). Note the article in OldNewThing does not handle Emojis, it just lets `TextOut` handle it (which is handled correctly in Windows 10 so the result appears okay)

---

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <usp10.h>
#include <AtlBase.h>
#include <AtlCom.h>
#include <mlang.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Usp10.lib")

int CALLBACK metafileproc(HDC, HANDLETABLE*, const ENHMETARECORD *record,
    int, LPARAM logfont)
{
    if(record->iType == EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW)
    {
        auto ptr = (const EMREXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW*)record;
        *(LOGFONT*)logfont = ptr->elfw.elfLogFont;
    }
    return 1;
}

HFONT GetFallbackFont(const wchar_t *str, HFONT hfont_test)
{
    //use metafile to find the fallback font
    auto metafile_hdc = CreateEnhMetaFile(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    auto metafile_oldfont = SelectObject(metafile_hdc, hfont_test);

    SCRIPT_STRING_ANALYSIS ssa;
    ScriptStringAnalyse(metafile_hdc, str, wcslen(str), 0, -1,
        SSA_METAFILE | SSA_FALLBACK | SSA_GLYPHS | SSA_LINK,
        0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &ssa);
    ScriptStringOut(ssa, 0, 0, 0, NULL, 0, 0, FALSE);
    ScriptStringFree(&ssa);

    SelectObject(metafile_hdc, metafile_oldfont);
    auto hmetafile = CloseEnhMetaFile(metafile_hdc);

    LOGFONT logfont = { 0 };
    EnumEnhMetaFile(0, hmetafile, metafileproc, &logfont, NULL);
    wprintf(L"Selecting fallback font: %s\n", logfont.lfFaceName);
    HFONT hfont = CreateFontIndirect(&logfont);
    DeleteEnhMetaFile(hmetafile);

    return hfont;
}

//IsTofu is for testing emojis
//It accepts a Unicode string
bool IsTofuError(HDC hdc, HFONT hfont_test, const wchar_t *str)
{
    if(wcsstr(str, L" "))
    {
        wprintf(L"*** cannot test strings containing blank space\n");
    }

    auto hfont = GetFallbackFont(str, hfont_test);
    auto oldfont = SelectObject(hdc, hfont);

    //find the characters not supported in this font
    //note, blank space is blank, unsupported fonts can be blank also
    SCRIPT_CACHE sc = NULL;
    SCRIPT_FONTPROPERTIES fp = { sizeof(fp) };
    ScriptGetFontProperties(hdc, &sc, &fp);
    ScriptFreeCache(&sc);
    wprintf(L"SCRIPT_FONTPROPERTIES:\n");
    wprintf(L" Blank: %d, Default: %d, Invalid: %d\n",
        fp.wgBlank, fp.wgDefault, fp.wgInvalid);

    // Get glyph indices for the string
    GCP_RESULTS gcp_results = { sizeof(GCP_RESULTS) };
    gcp_results.nGlyphs = wcslen(str);
    auto wstr_memory = (wchar_t*)calloc(wcslen(str) + 1, sizeof(wchar_t));
    gcp_results.lpGlyphs = wstr_memory;
    GetCharacterPlacement(hdc, str, wcslen(str), 0, &gcp_results, GCP_GLYPHSHAPE);

    //check the characters against wgBlank...
    bool istofu = false;
    wprintf(L"Glyphs:");
    for(UINT i = 0; i < gcp_results.nGlyphs; i++)
    {
        wchar_t n = gcp_results.lpGlyphs[i];
        wprintf(L"%d,", (int)n);
        if(n == fp.wgBlank || n == fp.wgInvalid || n == fp.wgDefault)
            istofu = true;
    }
    wprintf(L"\n");

    free(wstr_memory);
    SelectObject(hdc, oldfont);
    DeleteObject(hfont);

    if (istofu)
        wprintf(L"Tofu error\n\n");

    return istofu;
}

//get_font_link checks if there is font substitution, 
//this usually applies to Asian fonts
//Note, this function doesn't accept a unicode string
//it only takes a single code point. You can imrpove it to accept strings
bool get_font_link(const wchar_t *single_codepoint,
    HDC hdc,
    HFONT &hfont_src,
    HFONT &hfont_dst,
    CComPtr<IMLangFontLink> &ifont,
    CComPtr<IMLangCodePages> &icodepages)
{
    DWORD codepages_dst[100] = { 0 };
    LONG codepages_count = 100;

    DWORD codepages = 0;
    if(FAILED(icodepages->GetStrCodePages(single_codepoint, wcslen(single_codepoint),
        0, codepages_dst, &codepages_count)))
        return false;
    codepages = codepages_dst[0];

    if(FAILED(ifont->MapFont(hdc, codepages_dst[0], hfont_src, &hfont_dst)))
        return false;

    SelectObject(hdc, hfont_dst);
    wchar_t buf[100];
    GetTextFace(hdc, _countof(buf), buf);
    wprintf(L"get_font_link:\nSelecting a different font: %s\n", buf);
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    {
        CComPtr<IMultiLanguage> imultilang;
        CComPtr<IMLangFontLink> ifont;
        CComPtr<IMLangCodePages> icodepages;
        if(FAILED(imultilang.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CMultiLanguage))) return 0;
        if(FAILED(imultilang->QueryInterface(&ifont))) return 0;
        if(FAILED(imultilang->QueryInterface(&icodepages))) return 0;

        //const wchar_t *single_codepoint = L"a";
        //const wchar_t *single_codepoint = L"请";
        const wchar_t *single_codepoint = L"";

        auto hdc = GetDC(0);
        auto memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        auto hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 1, 1);
        auto oldbmp = SelectObject(memdc, hbitmap);
        auto hfont_src = CreateFont(10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, L"Segoe UI");
        auto oldfont = SelectObject(hdc, hfont_src);

        HFONT hfont_dst = NULL;

        if(IsTofuError(hdc, hfont_src, single_codepoint))
        {
            if(!get_font_link(
                single_codepoint, memdc, hfont_src, hfont_dst, ifont, icodepages))
                wprintf(L"Can't find a substitution!\n");
        }

        SelectObject(memdc, oldbmp);
        SelectObject(memdc, oldfont);
        DeleteObject(hbitmap);
        DeleteDC(memdc);
        ReleaseDC(0, hdc);
        DeleteObject(hfont_src);

        if(ifont && hfont_dst)
            ifont->ReleaseFont(hfont_dst);
    }

    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

`IsTofu` is `false` for Windows 10.

It will be `true` for some older Windows versions. But this is not tested in WinXP

<sub>Using `GetUniscribeFallbackFont` from [this link](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/ui/gfx/font_fallback_win.cc)</sub>

<sub>Note, Windows documentation describes `GetCharacterPlacement` as obsolete, it recommends using Uniscribe functions. But I don't know what replacement to use for it here.</sub>

Comment: Thank you! That's very cool, although I'm struggling to understand what you're doing there. Would you mind putting more comments into your `IsTofu` to explain it a little bit better? Also just to note. It doesn't work on WinXP -- `IsTofu` returns false. Although, can we safely assume that XP will not support surrogate pairs? And lastly, if the character is not a surrogate pair, can we use a simpler API for that: `WORD gi = 0; GetGlyphIndicesW(hdc, str, 1, &gi, GGI_MARK_NONEXISTING_GLYPHS);` and then check if `gi == -1` for non-supported glyphs?

Comment: I don't know about Windows XP. `GetGlyphIndices` looks similar to `GetCharacterPlacement` in this context. I don't know why `GetGlyphIndices` doesn't work. The odd part is using meta file to get the fallback font. After that it's just the gdi function `GetCharacterPlacement` to get the glyphs.

Comment: NT4 was UCS2 only, 2000 has some surrogate support and even more support in XP. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/intl/surrogates-and-supplementary-characters

Comment: @Anders: Hmm... thanks. Did you have a chance to see why his code doesn't seem to work under XP then?

Comment: @c00000fd Try the updated code, I think it should work in XP.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: Just curious, why are you creating a memory DC and a bitmap in your `main()`?

Comment: I didn't want to use `GetDC(0)`. You can use `HDC` if you have your own window.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: OK, thanks. It seems to work now. [Here's the results](https://i.imgur.com/BD9reOC.png).

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: I had to revisit your solution again. Unfortunately it failed in my recent tests. Couple issues: 1) there can be more than one `EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW` in the meta-file. Why do you only use the last one? and 2) here's an example of Chinese Unicode characters that don't work with your solution: `请阅读` if rendered on Windows 10 in a dialog box with the default `Microsoft Sans Serif(8)` font. All 3 glyphs will have `fp.wgBlank` flag, even though they can be displayed quite fine in the window. Is your proposed method for `surrogate pairs` only?

Comment: It will work for `请`, if you supply `"SimSun"` to `CreateFont`. If you start with `"Segoe UI"`, then the function correctly reports that `请` is not in `"Segoe UI"`. My font substitution function seems to work for emojis (newer emojis are surrogate pair) but doesn't work for some Asian languages. I'll have a look again, I think you have to go through a list of fonts in Windows registry, maybe `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontLink\SystemLink`

Comment: I added another function `get_font_link` to check for language font substitution. But now the code is limited to handling a single code point. You can test `"请" or `""` or `"A"` See the article in OldNewThing for expanding the code to handle strings.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: Thanks. Somehow SO didn't notify me of your replies. Let me try it all out. A quick question before that. Why are you using only the last `LOGFONT` in response to `EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW` type?

Comment: OK, well, technically it works with just using the last font. (It's above my pay-grade to see how else to parse that meta file output.) Thanks for your help. By the way, heads-up to whoever wants to use this code. I adjusted his last edit to fix the resource leak and also a buffer overflow vulnerability in the `get_font_link()` function. It would be nice not to include those, since quite a lot of people blindly copy code from SO into their commercial software. My adjusted code with a demo can be found [here on Github](https://github.com/ddbb2017/TestTofuGui).

Comment: I should have used `ifont->ReleaseFont`, I think you have fixed that in your code. I'll have to update this answer again.